# Java swt Canvas running loop

Tags: java, swt

I don't want to get called events during the render or update step, but before them. I also don't want to only redraw when an event has occurred, but as soon as possible, so I need a loop in my program.

- **poll events** - call functions to associated listeners
- **update** - may be merged with draw
- **draw**

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem, but if you want to draw continuously, then you should make a main loop. This thing cannot be made with swing components, but only if you design an event or use a predefined event. In that event, redraw the whole canvas, using `validate()` when you add a new component and `repaint()` or `paint()` when you just want to update the image.

If you don't want to render continuously then just render when "something" happens, such as when an event triggers.